# BeautifulSoup - how to get the text?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new here, I am learning Python. I really like it. I startet my own project to learn better and have now a problem where I need help.
I want to get the number 0 from `<span class=""><b>0</b>`. I tried a lot codes but with empty span class="" I can't get the .text. Can someone help me to get the 0?
Thank you.

my code now:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("link allowed to write?")
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
doc=BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")


for i in doc.select(".no-change"):
    for a in i.select(".dib"):
        print(a.find_all('span', class_=''))
```

output

```html
[<span class="">
      <b class="bg-green">2</b>
      <span>S</span>
 </span>,
 <span>S</span>,
 <span class="">
      <b>0</b>
      <span>U</span>
 </span>,
 <span>U</span>,
 <span class="">
      <b class="bg-red">1</b>
      <span>N</span>
 </span>, 
 <span>N</span>, 
 <span>
     <span class="icon-ball fs15 pr0 pl10" title="Torverhältniss">
     </span> 
     <span>5:5</span>
</span>,
<span>5:5</span>]
```

I want it like that:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(" -- ")
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
doc=BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

print(doc.select_one(".bg-green").text)
```

output
2

I tried a lot of codes. And expecting support how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect, with the link I was able to understand what you needed to retrieve.

In your case, via the html code that you can see via the source code of the page or the developer tool, you can see that the table (the one at the bottom) where your data is located is in a "div" whose class is "bb pb20 mb20". You can see in the code that I'm using this as a reference point. Once we've found the reference point, we need to use the find method to find the first "span" containing the text "U". Once we've found the "span" tag, all we need to do is retrieve the "child" tag using bs4's .find_previous_sibling function.

It's possible that I've misunderstood or that you want to retrieve another element (S or N), in which case you just need to change the "U" in: span_u = div_bilanz.find('span', text='U')

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.fussballdaten.de/vereine/tuerkei/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

div_data_match = soup.find('div', class_='bb pb20 mb20')
span_u = div_data_match.find('span', text='U')
result_u = span_u.find_previous_sibling('b').text
print('U :', result_u)
```

Comment: The site is [link](https://www.fussballdaten.de/vereine/tuerkei/) 
I want get the number 0 from this `<span class=""><b>0</b>`
you can see it on the site with the description: Form letzte 3 Spiele (in the middle is the number 0)

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you said. In this case, the information provided didn't seem sufficient to provide any help worthy of the name, which is why I asked for clarification of the need.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to get values from the `S`, `U`, `N` indicators under "Form letzte 3 Spiele":

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.fussballdaten.de/vereine/tuerkei/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

last_3_matches_form = soup.select('h2:-soup-contains("Form letzte 3 Spiele") + * b')
s, u, n = [t.text for t in last_3_matches_form]

print(f'{s=} {u=} {n=}')
```

Prints:

```
s='2' u='0' n='1'
```